# Annotate ggplot based on a second data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate

I have a faceted plot made with `ggplot` that is already working, it shows data about river altitude against years. I'm trying to add arrows based on a second dataframe which details when floods occurred.

Here's the current plot:
[image]

I would like to draw arrows in the top part of each graph based on date information in my second dataframe where each row corresponds to a flood and contains a date.
The link between the two dataframes is the `Station_code` column, each river has one or more stations which is indicated by this data (in this case only the Var river has two stations).

Here is the `dput` of the data frame used to create the original plot:

```
structure(list(River = c("Durance", "Durance", "Durance", "Durance", 
"Roya", "Var"), Reach = c("La Brillanne", "Les Mées", "La Brillanne", 
"Les Mées", "Basse vallée", "Basse vallée"), Area_km = c(465, 
465, 465, 465, 465, 465), Type = c("restored", "target", "restored", 
"target", "witness", "restored"), Year = c(2017, 2017, 2012, 
2012, 2018, 2011), Restoration_year = c(2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
NA, 2009), Station_code = c("X1130010", "X1130010", "X1130010", 
"X1130010", "Y6624010", "Y6442015"), BRI_adi_moy_sstransect = c(0.00375820736746399, 
0.00244752138003355, 0.00446807607783864, 0.0028792618981479, 
0.00989200896930529, 0.00357247516596474), SD_sstransect = c(0.00165574247612667, 
0.0010044634990875, 0.00220534492332107, 0.00102694633805149, 
0.00788573233793128, 0.00308489160008849), min_BRI_sstransect = c(0.00108123849595469, 
0.00111493913953216, 0.000555500340370182, 0.00100279590198288, 
0, 0), max_BRI_sstransect = c(0.0127781240385231, 0.00700537285706352, 
0.0210216858227621, 0.00815151653110584, 0.127734814926934, 0.0223738711013954
), Nb_sstr_unique_m = c(0.00623321576795815, 0.00259754717331206, 
0.00117035034437559, 0.00209845092352825, 0.0458628969163946, 
3.60620609570031), BRI_adi_moy_transect = c(0.00280232169999531, 
0.00173868254527501, 0.00333818552810438, 0.00181398859573415, 
0.00903651639185542, 0.00447856455432537), SD_transect = c(0.00128472161839638, 
0.000477209421076879, 0.00204050725984513, 0.000472466654940182, 
0.00780731734792112, 0.00310039904793707), min_BRI_transect = c(0.00108123849595469, 
0.00106445386542223, 0.000901992689363725, 0.000855135344651009, 
0.000944414463851629, 0.000162012161197014), max_BRI_transect = c(0.00709151795418251, 
0.00434366293208643, 0.011717024999411, 0.0031991369873946, 0.127734814926934, 
0.0187952134332499), Nb_tr_unique_m = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Error_reso = c(0.0011, 
8e-04, 0.0018, 0.0011, 0.0028, 0.0031), W_BA = c(296.553323029366, 
411.056574923547, 263.944186046512, 363.32874617737, 88.6420798065296, 
158.66866970576), W_BA_sd = c(84.1498544481585, 65.3909073242282, 
100.067554749308, 55.5534084807705, 35.2337070278364, 64.6978349498119
), W_BA_min = c(131, 206, 33, 223, 6, 45), W_BA_max = c(472, 
564, 657, 513, 188, 381), W_norm = c(5.73271228619998, 7.9461900926133, 
5.10234066090722, 7.02355699765464, 5.09378494746752, 4.81262001531126
), W_norm_sd = c(1.62671218635823, 1.2640804493236, 1.93441939783807, 
1.07391043231191, 2.02469218788178, 1.96236658443141), W_norm_min = c(2.53237866910643, 
3.98221378500706, 0.637927450996277, 4.31084307794454, 0.344787822572658, 
1.36490651299098), W_norm_max = c(9.12429566273463, 10.9027600715727, 
12.7005556152895, 9.91687219276031, 10.8033517739433, 11.5562084766569
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

And here is the `dput` of the date frame containing the flooding date:

```
structure(list(Station_code = c("Y6042010", "Y6042010", "Y6042010", 
"Y6042010", "Y6042010", "Y6042010"), Date = structure(c(12006, 
12007, 12016, 12017, 13416, 13488), class = "Date"), Qm3s = c(156, 
177, 104, 124, 125, 90.4), Qual = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), Year = c(2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2006, 2006), Month = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 9, 12
), Station_river = c("Var@Entrevaux", "Var@Entrevaux", "Var@Entrevaux", 
"Var@Entrevaux", "Var@Entrevaux", "Var@Entrevaux"), River = c("Var", 
"Var", "Var", "Var", "Var", "Var"), Mod_inter = c(13.32, 13.32, 
13.32, 13.32, 13.32, 13.32), Qm3s_norm = c(11.7117117117117, 
13.2882882882883, 7.80780780780781, 9.30930930930931, 9.38438438438438, 
6.78678678678679), File_name = c("Var@Entrevaux.dat", "Var@Entrevaux.dat", 
"Var@Entrevaux.dat", "Var@Entrevaux.dat", "Var@Entrevaux.dat", 
"Var@Entrevaux.dat"), Station_name = c("@Entrevaux", "@Entrevaux", 
"@Entrevaux", "@Entrevaux", "@Entrevaux", "@Entrevaux"), Reach = c("Daluis", 
"Daluis", "Daluis", "Daluis", "Daluis", "Daluis"), Restauration_year = c(2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009), `Area_km[BH]` = c(676, 676, 676, 
676, 676, 676), Starting_year = c(1920, 1920, 1920, 1920, 1920, 
1920), Ending_year = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), Accuracy = c("good", 
"good", "good", "good", "good", "good"), Q2 = c(86, 86, 86, 86, 
86, 86), Q5 = c(120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120), Q10 = c(150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150), Q20 = c(170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170), Q50 = c(200, 
200, 200, 200, 200, 200), Data_producer = c("DREAL_PACA", "DREAL_PACA", 
"DREAL_PACA", "DREAL_PACA", "DREAL_PACA", "DREAL_PACA"), Coord_X_L2e_Z32 = c(959313, 
959313, 959313, 959313, 959313, 959313), Coord_Y_L2e_Z32 = c(1893321, 
1893321, 1893321, 1893321, 1893321, 1893321), Coord_X_L93 = c(1005748.88, 
1005748.88, 1005748.88, 1005748.88, 1005748.88, 1005748.88), 
    Coord_Y_L93 = c(6324083.97, 6324083.97, 6324083.97, 6324083.97, 
    6324083.97, 6324083.97), New_FN = c("Var@Entrevaux.csv", 
    "Var@Entrevaux.csv", "Var@Entrevaux.csv", "Var@Entrevaux.csv", 
    "Var@Entrevaux.csv", "Var@Entrevaux.csv"), NA_perc = c(14.92, 
    14.92, 14.92, 14.92, 14.92, 14.92), Q2_norm = c(6.45645645645646, 
    6.45645645645646, 6.45645645645646, 6.45645645645646, 6.45645645645646, 
    6.45645645645646), Q5_norm = c(9.00900900900901, 9.00900900900901, 
    9.00900900900901, 9.00900900900901, 9.00900900900901, 9.00900900900901
    ), Q10_norm = c(11.2612612612613, 11.2612612612613, 11.2612612612613, 
    11.2612612612613, 11.2612612612613, 11.2612612612613), Q20_norm = c(12.7627627627628, 
    12.7627627627628, 12.7627627627628, 12.7627627627628, 12.7627627627628, 
    12.7627627627628), Q50_norm = c(15.015015015015, 15.015015015015, 
    15.015015015015, 15.015015015015, 15.015015015015, 15.015015015015
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(Station_code = "Y6042010", 
    .rows = structure(list(1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**EDIT**

Here is an example of what I would like to do on the plot:

[image]

This is the code I use currently to do the plot:

```
  ggplot(data = tst_formule[tst_formule$River != "Roya",], aes(x = Year, y = BRI_adi_moy_transect, shape = River, col = Type)) +  
  geom_point(size = 3) +    
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = BRI_adi_moy_transect - SD_transect, ymax = BRI_adi_moy_transect + SD_transect), size = 0.7, width = 0.3) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = BRI_adi_moy_transect - Error_reso, ymax = BRI_adi_moy_transect + Error_reso, linetype = "Error due to resolution"), size = 0.3, width = 0.3, colour = "black") +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = NULL, values = 2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 18, 17, 16)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("chocolate1", "darkcyan")) +  
  new_scale("linetype") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = Restoration_year, linetype = "Restoration"), colour = "chocolate1") + 
  scale_linetype_manual(name = NULL, values = 5) +
  new_scale("linetype") +  
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0.004, linetype = "Threshold"), colour= 'black') + 
  scale_linetype_manual(name = NULL, values = 4) + 
  scale_y_continuous("BRI*", limits = c(min(tst_formule$BRI_adi_moy_transect - tst_formule$SD_transect, tst_formule$BRI_adi_moy_transect - tst_formule$Error_reso ), max(tst_formule$BRI_adi_moy_transect + tst_formule$SD_transect, tst_formule$BRI_adi_moy_transect + tst_formule$Error_reso))) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(min(tst_formule$Year - 1),max(tst_formule$Year + 1)), breaks = scales::breaks_pretty(n = 6)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  facet_wrap(vars(River)) + 
  theme(legend.spacing.y = unit(-0.01, "cm")) + 
  guides(shape = guide_legend(order = 1),  
         colour = guide_legend(order = 2),
         line = guide_legend(order = 3))
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you used to plot the data, as a reproducible example? Also, can you illustrate (with for example paint) on the current plot what you would like to happen? The description you give of where you want the arrows isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tests and more research, I managed to do it by adding the second dataframe in `geom_text()`:

```
new_scale("linetype") +
  geom_segment(data = Flood_plot, aes(x = Date, xend = Date, y = 0.025, yend = 0.020, linetype = "Morphogenic flood"), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm")), inherit.aes = F, guide = guide_legend(order = 6)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = NULL, values = 1) +
```

`new_scale()` creates a new `linetype` definition after the ones I created before, `geom_segment()` allows to draw arrows which I wanted but it works with `geom_text()` and `scale_linetype_manual()` draws the arrow in the legend without the mention "linetype" above. The second dataframe has the same column (River) as the 1st one to wrap and create the panels.

[image]